# Elasticsearch 2.0 script_score from Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've just upgraded to ES 2.0.0-rc1.
I use a local node for JUnit testing.

```
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("script.inline", "on")
            .put("script.indexed", "on")
            .put("path.home", "/").build();

    return NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
            .settings(settings)
            .local(true)
            .clusterName("c").node();
```

My problem is that the upgraded version doesn't see my native scripts.

The query seems like this:

```
        Script script = new Script("myscript", ScriptType.INDEXED, "native", params);
        ScoreFunctionBuilder scoreBuilder = ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction(script);
```

The output is the following:

```
...
"functions" : [ {
  "script_score" : {
    "script" : {
      "id" : "myscript",
      "lang" : "native",
      "params" : {
        "searchMode" : "A"
      }
    }
  }
...
```

This script Plugin is in the Maven dependency list.

It worked well with the former version however with this new version I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: script_score the script could not be loaded

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.IndexNotFoundException: no such index
```

So how could I install the plugin to a local node?

**Edit 1:**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugin-authors.html / Loading plugins from the classpath

might be the solution. Nope.

**Edit 2:**

It seems that the ScoreFunctionBuilder has been changed.

1.7:

```
ScoreFunctionBuilder scoreBuilder = ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction("myscript", "native", params);
```

2.0:

```
Script script = new Script("myscript", ScriptType.INDEXED, "native", params);
ScoreFunctionBuilder scoreBuilder = ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction(script);
```

However this doesn't fits to native scripts.

Comment: Can I revive this question?  I am experiencing the exact same issue after upgrading from 1.x to 2.1.0.  I have a plugin that registers a native java script.  I can see in the logs that the plugin indeed invokes the onModule(ScriptModule) method and registers the native script's factory.  When I try to use the script with script_score, ES tries to find the script in the ".scripts" index, which does not exist.  I am specifying the script is "lang":"native" and the "id" is correct.  Any ideas what the heck is going on?

Comment: When I form a POST that looks like this (without "id") it works:
{
 "script_score": {
  "script": "my_script",
        "lang": "native",
  "params": {}
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why since it doesn't follow any logic but all you need to do is to use `ScriptType.INLINE`

```
Script script = new Script("myscript", ScriptType.INLINE, "native", params);
```

We can't use INDEXED because elasticsearch will look for an indexed script in its system and since our script isn't indexed per say... it wouldn't work.